# Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Framework.Logging.LoggerFactory.AddProvider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using version "7.0.0-beta5-13087" of the EntityFramework.SqlServer nightly nuget packages.

When I perform this Add-Migration:

```
Add-Migration initial -Project DataAccess.Contexts.SqlServer -Context DbNameSqlServerContext -StartupProject UserInterfaces.Web -Verbose
```

I get the following error:

```
Add-Migration : Exception calling "CreateInstanceAndUnwrap" with "8" argument(s): "Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Framework.Logging.LoggerFactory.AddProvider(Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILoggerProvider)'."
```

I found a couple of references to the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap Exception and method not found, but neither were related to EF7 nor did I feel like they were pointing me in the right direction.

As a complete guess, I tried adding Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console (and its dependent packages) and even tried wiring it up to the DI container that my context is loaded in hopes that if I was hitting some different path that required logging to be injected, it would be available.  It didn't work.

I recreated a very similar, but simpler (fewer entities) solution, and am able to get the migration to work.

I suspect that this is likely not an EF nightly issue and is more likely something wrong with the configuration of my context, but I'm stumped on what could be the cause.

Do you have ideas on what the cause of the Exception might be and what I could try to get the migration to add?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your project.json? It looks like somewhere you have mismatched versions.

Comment: My EntityFramework.Commands nuget package was out of sync with the rest of the EF packages I was using.  Thanks for the help Brice.